# Inflating a tablelayout in an expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

My TableLayout is not inflating once for each parent view. Instead, the TableLayout doesn't inflate at all for the first parent, inflates once for the second parent and inflates twice for the third parent.

Any thoughts on why the Tablelayout doesn't inflate once per parent view?

**Main Class**

```
package com.example.jbunn.gi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class LeaderBoard extends Activity {

    ExpandableListView exv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leader_board);
        exv = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }

}
```

**MyAdapter Class**

```
package com.example.jbunn.gi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mLi;

    String [] parentList = {"James", "Matt", "Rhodus"};

    public MyAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
    mContext = context;
    mLi = (LayoutInflater)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


static class ViewHolderItem {
    TableLayout tl;
}
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i2) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        TextView tv = new EditText(context);
        tv.setText(parentList[i]);
        tv.setPadding(50,0,0,0);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i2, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    if(convertView ==null){
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childgridview, parent, false);
        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.tl = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childgridview);
        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
        return false;
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/childgridview">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:text="1"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:text="2"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:text="3"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:text="4"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:text="5"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:text="6"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:text="7"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:text="8"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:text="9"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ten"
            android:text="10"
            android:padding="10dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eleven"
            android:text="11"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/twelve"
            android:text="12"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirteen"
            android:text="13"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourteen"
            android:text="14"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fifteen"
            android:text="15"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sixteen"
            android:text="16"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seventeen"
            android:text="17"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eighteen"
            android:text="18"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the value of `childList` set? As an aside, you should also consider using a [`SimpleExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html), perhaps.

Comment: And the `TableLayout` you are attempting to inflate is where? The R.layout.childgridview?

Comment: I removed the childList from getChildView but forgot to remove it from getChildrenCount. Thus, for this example, the childList variable should not exist. Yes, the TableLayout is from R.layout.childgridview.

Comment: I removed the childList variable from the code and edited the getChildView to return view.

Comment: Okay, I got it to inflate the TableLayout. However, the TableLayout doesn't show for the first parent, it displays for the second parent and it displays 2 times on the third parent. How can I display the TableLayout once for each parent?

Comment: I would not request teh `LayoutInflater` in every call of `getChild`. Move it into the constructor as a class collaborator, is the `ViewHolder` pattern needed here. Having a `TableLayout` inside of a `ListView` item just seems wrong (performance and crazy ux wise)

Comment: Thanks Blundell. I'm new to android, could you assist me with how to move the layoutInflater into the constructor as a class collaborator? Also, should moving the layoutInflater cause the TableLayout to display once for each parent? I've given it a try in the edited code above. I also tried to implement the viewHolder design pattern in the getChildView call.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the getChildrenCount method to return a "1" instead of i, the TableLayout displayed once for each parent.